# jQuery toggle button is toggling all divs instead of the single desired one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have several "newscard" divs and they all get toggled by the button. I need to toggle the "cardexpand" of only the "newscard" the button is inside of.

Ps. this is my 1st question on this website so please pardon any untoward stuff.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".cardexpand").hide();
        $(".expand").click(function(){
            $(this).next(".cardexpand").toggle(1000);
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="newscard">
    <img src="news1.jpg" class="img">
    <div class="cardbody">
        <p class="cardtitle">James Blyat does not associate with Vainglory players</p>
        <p class="carddetails">Mar 29, 2019 • Gaming</p>
        <button class="expand">Expand</button>
    </div>
    <div class="cardexpand">
        <hr class="cardhr"></hr>
        <p class="cardtext">
            Vainglory is just anime of the gaming world and is 
            for weebs, he says. Vainglory is just anime of the gaming world and is 
            for weebs, he says.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry but that (this).next wasnt supposed to be a part of the code. i was just trying to fix this and forgot to erase it. and yes it didnt work :(

Answer (score 0):

The `next()` function is not going to work because the `button` is not a sibling of the container you want to toggle.  You have to select the parent first.  Try this:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".cardexpand").hide();
  $(".expand").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().next(".cardexpand").toggle(1000);
  });
});
</script>

<div class="newscard">
<img src="news1.jpg" class="img">
<div class="cardbody">
<p class="cardtitle">James Blyat does not associate with Vainglory 
players</p>
<p class="carddetails">Mar 29, 2019 • Gaming</p>
<button class="expand">Expand</button>
</div>
<div class="cardexpand"><hr class="cardhr"></hr>
<p class="cardtext">Vainglory is just anime of the gaming world and is 
for weebs, he says. Vainglory is just anime of the gaming world and is 
for weebs, he says.
</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="newscard">
<img src="news1.jpg" class="img">
<div class="cardbody">
<p class="cardtitle">James Blyat does not associate with Vainglory 
players</p>
<p class="carddetails">Mar 29, 2019 • Gaming</p>
<button class="expand">Expand</button>
</div>
<div class="cardexpand"><hr class="cardhr"></hr>
<p class="cardtext">Vainglory is just anime of the gaming world and is 
for weebs, he says. Vainglory is just anime of the gaming world and is 
for weebs, he says.
</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you also tell me how to make the entire newscard div toggle the cardexpand instead of just the expand button? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
$(this).closest(".newscard").find(".cardexpand").toggle(1000);
```

Here, [closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) searches "up the DOM tree" until it finds a matching element. From there, we use [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) to search inside the found element for elements matching `.cardexpand`.

Comment: Can you also tell me how to make the entire newscard div toggle the cardexpand instead of just the expand button? Thanks a lot

Comment: Just use a different selector when attaching the event handler, and modify the selector inside the handler if necessary. Use `console.log()` to debug.